# What is the name of the cognitive bias about groups of people with the same beliefs about others?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology, bias, attitudes

Last year I read an interesting magazine article about some papers on a cognitive bias about group beliefs.

The papers highlight the fact that we tend to judge in a stronger way the same behavior if the person is not part of our social circle. So for example we tend to judge smokers more harshly if they are not our relatives.

I am looking for the name and/or references to this cognitive bias.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [in-group favouritism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-group_favoritism):

> ... a pattern of favoring members of one's in-group over out-group
> members. This can be expressed in evaluation of others, in allocation
> of resources, and in many other ways.

Also see more generally: [In-group_and_out-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-group_and_out-group).